# Right way to draw with javascript emoticon selection element that should look like one in skype

Tags: javascript, emoticons

I need the element which looks like rectangle image that consists of emoticons, say x emoticons in vertical direction and y emoticons in horizontal dimension.

It could be drawn as a *table* or as a *list* or as a *set of paragraphs*, or it could be an actual *composite image with usermap* attached, styled e.g. with ImageMapper.

What way would you suggest? Maybe you would recommend a good lesson or example?

I'd like emoticons images to be loaded at the time page loads and the html fragment with element code to be server side generated, because I want to enable icon/disable icon/to set icons positions in the menu dynamically.

Comment: I would say that the decision between composite image and the other options, is likely driven by how the emoticons fit into your model.  Are they a single static thing that you'll update monolithically, or does it make sense to define and render them individually?  If it's the former then it makes sense to have **one thing** (the composite image); otherwise, better to have separate images and render them in some sort of collection.

Comment: Each emoticon is an object, that has attributes: image filename, e.g. _ab.gif_, code e.g. _:-)_ and name, e.g. _smile_